# AttributeError with ExecuteSQL

Tags: gdal

I'm using the Python bindings for GDAL to do some processing on a set of satellite imagery. In my preprocessing step, I'm attempting to use ExecuteSQL; however, I've been getting a strange AttributeError that I can't find any solutions to.  Here is a snippet of my relevant code:

```
def preprocess(full_lyr):

# Preprocess for park boundaries
UNIX_time = ogr.FieldDefn('ACQ_SECOND', ogr.OFTInteger)
full_lyr.CreateField(UNIX_time)

# create acquire seconds field
for i in full_lyr:
    full_lyr.SetFeature(i)
    dt = datetime.datetime.strptime(i.GetField('ACQ_DATE'), '%Y/%m/%d')
    new_time = time.mktime(dt.timetuple())
    new_time = new_time + float((i.GetField("ACQ_TIME") * 60))
    i.SetField("ACQ_SECOND", new_time)
    full_lyr.SetFeature(i)

layerName = full_lyr.GetName()
layer = full_lyr.ExecuteSQL('select * from "%s"' % layerName)
```

When run, I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/cschenker/anaconda/envs/garamba/fireEvent/Preprocess", 
    line 79, in <module> preprocess(whole_lyr)
  File "/Users/cschenker/anaconda/envs/garamba/fireEvent/Preprocess", 
    line 47, in preprocess
    layer = full_lyr.ExecuteSQL('select * from "%s"' % layerName)
  File "/Users/cschenker/anaconda/envs/FIRES/lib/python3.6/site-
    packages/osgeo/ogr.py", line 1397, in <lambda>
    __getattr__ = lambda self, name: _swig_getattr(self, Layer, name)
  File "/Users/cschenker/anaconda/envs/FIRES/lib/python3.6/site-
    packages/osgeo/ogr.py", line 74, in _swig_getattr
    return _swig_getattr_nondynamic(self, class_type, name, 0)
  File "/Users/cschenker/anaconda/envs/FIRES/lib/python3.6/site-
    packages/osgeo/ogr.py", line 69, in _swig_getattr_nondynamic
    return object.__getattr__(self, name)
  AttributeError: type object 'object' has no attribute '__getattr__'
```

Any input on how to remedy this? It could be due to a compatibility issue with swig within my conda environment, but I haven't come across any GDAL users with a similar problem.

Answer (score 2):

`ExecuteSQL` is a method of a `DataSource` object, not a `Layer`.

Use something like the following instead:

```
data_source = ogr.Open(dataset)
full_lyr = data_source .GetLayer(0)
layerName = full_lyr.GetName()
new_lyr = data_source.ExecuteSQL('select * from "%s"' % layerName)
```